# How to duplicate a column to a list of comma delimited items in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

I am trying to figure out how to append the id to each item in the tags list.  For example I have a item id of 01 and its corresponding tags are Recycled, leather, case, holder, iPad, snap, kindle.  I am trying to figure out how to output the data in a way that it can be exported from mySQL line by line.

```
01;Recycled
01;leather
01;case
01;.....
02;agrarian
02;urban

id             tags
01     Recycled, leather, case, holder, iPad, snap, kindle
02     agrarian, urban, planter, eco, ...
```

I have tried pulling the id into a table, I have tried using substring to parse the data, but I just can't figure out how to get the data the way I am looking for.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you normalize the data model then this problem (and many other problems) becomes moot.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want `group_concat()`:

```
select id, group_concat(tag separator ', ') as tags
from t
group by id;
```